# $-\log(X)$ transformation of beta-distributed random variable $X$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation, density-function

Let $X \sim \text{Beta}_{(\theta, 1)} =: \mathbb{P}_\theta$ be a continuous random variable where
$$\mathbb{f}_\theta(x) := \theta \cdot x^{\theta-1}\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]} = \cases{\theta \cdot x^{\theta-1}  \hspace{10pt} \text{x}\in [0,1]\\0  \hspace{33pt} \text{x}\in [0,1]}$$

Calculate the distribution of the random variable $Y := -\log(X)$. My first attempt looks like this:

Let $h(x) := -\log(x)$. We get $h'(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$ and $h^{-1}(x) = e^{-x}$. Now I apply the density transformation:

$$\mathbb{f}^Y(y) = \frac{\mathbb{f}^X(h^{-1}(y))}{|\det(h'(h^{-1}(y)))|} = e^{-y} \cdot \theta \cdot {(e^{-y})}^{\theta-1}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(y) = \theta e^{-\theta \cdot y}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(y)$$

This result doesn't seem right to me, since it's integral is not equal to $1$, but I can't seem to find a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is somewhat confusing, let me denote by $f_X()$ and  $f_Y()$ the densities of $X,Y$

Then , if $Y=h(X)$ and $h$ is monotonic and differentiable, we have

$$\begin{align} 
f_Y(y)&=\left.{\frac{f_X(x)}{|h'(x)|}}\right|_{x=h^{-1}(y)}\\
&= \left. \frac{\theta \cdot x^{\theta-1}  }{1/x} [0\le x\le 1] \right|_{x=h^{-1}(y)}\\
&= \left. \theta x^{\theta} \, [0\le x\le 1] \right|_{x=\exp(-y)} \\
&= \theta e^{- \theta y } \,  [0\le e^{-y}\le 1] \\
&= \theta e^{- \theta y } \,  [y\ge 0] \\
\end{align}
$$

which is an exponential.

Your error was in doing the change of variable within the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). Here, I'm using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) notation instead.